# onEdit / onForm submit - code initiated but no action

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I have set up a function to send an email to my email when any change is made, so I can be notified when a maintenance request is added to the sheet. I want to set it up so my trigger only occurs when a certain column (in this case A) or row is changed - as I wasn't receiving notifications with on Form Submit for some reason.

Here is my code -

```
function onEdit(e){ 
var range = e.range; if (range.getColumn() === A && range.getRow() === observedCellRow) { 

sendEmail(); MailApp.sendEmail('connor@singapm.com','Email Subject','Email Message' } }
```

What else needs to be included in this code to get an email when 'A' Column is changed/added to? Please note I have no experience whatsoever in scripting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. You cannot fire an `onEdit` trigger on FormSubmit

- `onEdit` only detects edits that have been performed by a human, not form submissions .
- If you want to fire your function when a new form submission takes place, please bind the [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onFormSubmit` to your function.
- You can do so by going to `Edit->Current Project triggers` and selecting `+ Add Trigger`.
- If you want your function to fire both on (human-made) edit and on form submisison - you can have more than one trigger bound to the same function.

### 2.You cannot send an email triggered by a [simple `onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

- See [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

> They [simple triggers] cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization.

- So, to run your function `onEdit` please install the installable version of the `onEdit` instead of the simple one.
- Please rename your function in order to deactivate the simple `onEdit` trigger (having both the simple and installable `onEdit` triggered active simultaneously can lead to not desired behavior).